# How to create legend in faceted box plot on ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do i get rid of the x-axis labels that are all overlapping, and instead create a legend and filter by colour?

```
library(ggplot2)
#Load in the dataset
broadband = read.csv("broadbanddata.csv")
#Box plot 
ggplot(broadband) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = rsp, y = All.hour.trimmed.mean.latency)) +
  labs(title="Figure 1: Average internet speed", x="Type of technology", y="Average Latency in a Day")+
  facet_wrap(~technology)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   library(ggplot2)
#Load in the dataset
broadband = read.csv("broadbanddata.csv")
#Box plot 
ggplot(broadband) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = rsp, 
                                     y = All.hour.trimmed.mean.latency, 
                                     fill = rsp)) +
        labs(title="Figure 1: Average internet speed",
             x="Type of technology",
             y="Average Latency in a Day",
             fill = "Average Latency in a Day")+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
        facet_wrap(~technology)
```